# Python:How to implement multiple dynamic mock.patch functions?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I am trying to dynamically mock/patch multiple @property methods of a class in python i.e.

```
class Dog():
     ...

     @property
     def size(self):
        .....

     @property
     def breed(self):
        .....


cases = [{"size":9, "breed":"doberman"}, {"size":2, "breed":"pug"}]

@pytest.mark.parametrize("case", list(cases.values()), ids=list(cases.keys()))
def test_properties(case):

    dog = Dog()
    mocks = ()

    for m, v in case.items():
       mocks += (mock.patch.object(dog, m, return_value=v),)

    with mocks:
        ...
```

However, I get the following error:

> ```
>       with mocks:
> ```
>
> E           AttributeError: **enter**

Clearly this is not the appropriate method of mocking multiple properties according to a config as shown above? Could someone please advise me on how to best achieve this, thanks!

Comment: `cases.values()`? it is a list of dict

Comment: pytest iterates over each case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest option for you would be using `contextlib.ExitStack`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#supporting-a-variable-number-of-context-managers

Another option would be using pytest's `monkeypatch` fixture: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/monkeypatch.html

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the answer from Alex, the following solved it:

```
if "mock" in case:
        for m,v in case["mock"].items():
            def get_value(self):return v
            monkeypatch.setattr(State, m, property(get_value))
```